# Tokenizing texts in both Chinese and English improperly splits English words into letters

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, tokenize

When tokenizing texts that contain both Chinese and English, the result will split English words into letters, which is not what I want. Consider the following code:

```
from nltk.tokenize.stanford_segmenter import StanfordSegmenter
segmenter = StanfordSegmenter()
segmenter.default_config('zh')
print(segmenter.segment('哈佛大学的Melissa Dell'))
```

The output will be `哈佛大学 的 M e l i s s a D e l l`. How do I modify this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

You could try jieba.

```
import jieba
jieba.lcut('哈佛大学的Melissa Dell')
['哈佛大学', '的', 'Melissa', ' ', 'Dell']
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for `nltk` , but Stanford CoreNLP will not exhibit this behavior if run on this sentence.

If you issue this command on your example you get proper tokenization:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

You might want to look into using `stanza` if you want to access Stanford CoreNLP via Python.

More info here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza